# Import statement clarification

Tags: java, import, package

What is the difference between `"import java.lang.Integer;"` and `" import java.lang.Integer.*;".`

I have read on internet that the Integer is a class inside the lang package. If this is true then then `" import java.lang.Integer.*;"` should give an compilation error because the statement `" import java.lang.Integer.*;"` mean to import all the classes inside the package *Integer* but *Integer* is not a package it is a class.

But both statements compile without any error.

Please clarify. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: What if class has another class withing? Try something like import java.util.Map.*;

Comment: how do you know that this isn't valid package name ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.lang.Integer.*;
```

The above statement is a less common form of `import`, allows you to import the public nested classes of an enclosing class(in this case Integer class).

Consider for example, if the `graphics.Rectangle` class contained useful nested classes, such as `Rectangle.DoubleWide` and `Rectangle.Square`, you could import Rectangle and its nested classes by using the following two statements.

```
import graphics.Rectangle;
import graphics.Rectangle.*;
```

Be aware that the second import statement will not import Rectangle.

Answer (score 1):

If i will write "import java.lang.Integer;" so its a particular find Integer Function only.
if I will write "import java.lang.Integer.*; so Its all function Included which Extension of "java.lang.integer".